# How can I use the information of a field from one model to calculate another field in other model?

Tags: python, django

Im creating a restaurant software with python and Django. I have an Ingredient model that has cost and quantity fields. I use them to return the cost_per_unit calculated field (cost / quantity).

```py
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    ingredient = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    quantity = models.FloatField()
    unit_of_measure = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=UNIT_CHOICES)
    cost = models.FloatField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def cost_per_unit(self):
        cost_per_unit = self.cost / self.quantity
        return cost_per_unit

    def __str__(self):
        """Return username."""
        return self.ingredient
```

Then, I created a recipe model, with the fields: ingredient as Foreign key, ingredient_quantity and cost_per_ingredient.

```py
class Recipe(models.Model):
    ingredient_name = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient)
    ingredient_quantity = models.FloatField()
    unit_of_measure = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=UNIT_CHOICES)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    def cost_per_ingredient(self):
        cost_per_ingredient = self.ingredient_quantity # * cost_per_unit
        return cost_per_ingredient
```

How can I use the information that I already have in the Ingredient model (cost_per_unit) to calculate the cost_per_ingredient (it would be cost_per_unit * ingredient_quantity) ?

Comment: Is it possible to share your modeling, the current descriptions is not very *accessible*, likely if you show the models for the `Recipe`, `Ingredient`, etc. it is easier to understand how to implement this.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I already upload the models information. Thanks!

Comment: Recipe can only have one ingredient?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the Ingredient object fields through the ingredient foreign key:

```py
class Recipe(models.Model):
    ...
    def cost_per_ingredient(self):
        cost_per_ingredient = self.ingredient_quantity * self.ingredient_name.cost_per_unit
        return cost_per_ingredient
```

I would suggest to call it "ingredient" though, not "ingredient_name".